# On click on save or submit button, Cursor should automatically come to missing text Field

Tags: java, android

```
if(productItem.ProductName.equals(""))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Product Name...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ((InputMethodManager) MainFormActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                        .showSoftInput(pName, 0);
            }
```

This code is not working for me, I want to Every time on click on save button it should validate the missing field, and if something missing cursor should come to missing field.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but `productItem.ProductName` looks to me like a class with an attribute that you made. If you want to check the text in an `EditText` you should change your if statement to something like this:

```
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.textID);
if(txt.GetText().Equals("")){
  //do something
{
```

In this way you are going to check if the `EditText` in your layout is empty when you click the button.

Comment: Yes this part is OK, but I am only struggling with to get Cursor on missing field..

Comment: If you want to set the focus on the `EditText` that is blank, you can use this piece of code: `txt.requestFocus();` and should make the selected item on your layout the said `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

try this in validation it will display the red ballon on edit text as blank if(edittext.lenth()<=0) edittext.setError(error msg);